# how to echo data that we read with file_get_contents

Tags: php, function, if-statement, file-get-contents

i want to check remote url's page contents. IF remote site's page content contains string http://yahoo.com set $qqq = YH if not contains $qqq = NOYH. i am not talking about "url of that page" im talking about page content of url

```
$url = "'".$get['url']."'";
$needle = "http://yahoo.com/";
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
if(stripos($contents, $needle) !== false) {
    $qqq = "YH";
}
```

But it's not working. Can anybody help me with the correct syntax? thanks..

Comment: where's your `echo $qqq;` line?

Comment: i want to do is SET $qqq = "YH" if "http://somedomain.com/topic.php?id=43242" contains "http://yahoo.com"

Comment: `<?=$qqq?>` will indeed echo `$qqq`. See [php.net/echo](http://dk2.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).

Comment: It seems that is exactly what your code will do for you, I cannot test it though since I am at work. But for your original question, to *echo* the variable, you need to call `echo`

Comment: You mean if the page content contains "yahoo.com", or the URL itself?

Comment: @Anthony - he's using PHP short tags to echo.

Comment: @Sebastian, @zombat: Thank you for clarifying, it's been a while.

Comment: All in all your whole question is inconsistent. In your title, you ask how you can echo data that you receive via `file_get_contents`. In the text you said you want to check whether the URL contains a certain string and you want to echo `YH`. In the comments you say you want to  check whether the document the URL is referring to contains a certain string... Sigh...

Comment: @Felix Kling: I am in the same boat with you brother :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think your code won't work. For a number of reasons:

1. In your first line, you create a string, that contains single-quotes. So basically, `$url` contains something like `'http://url.here'`. If you pass this to `file_get_contents` you get an error:

   ```
   $url = "'http://www.google.com'";
   echo file_get_contents($url);

   Warning: file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/'): failed to open stream: 
   No such file or directory in ...
   ```
2. You said want to check whether `$url` contains a certain string. But you are checking whether **the document** the URL is pointing to, contains this string.

<del>3. Maybe you mean `$_GET` instead of `$get` to retrieve the parameter `url` that is contained in the URL?</del>

Ok, I read from the comments that you indeed want to search for the string in the **content**. Still, the first line of code is wrong, so it is probably:

```
$needle = "http://yahoo.com/";
$contents = file_get_contents($get['url']);
if(stripos($contents, $needle) !== false) {
    $qqq = "YH";
}
```

(`<?= $qqq ?>` should work as it is).

Comment: i didnt mean $_GET.. $get is mysql_fetch_arrayed mysql query. i tried your last edit. it makes my page unloadable. its never loading.

Comment: @Ronnie, it might makes sense to edit the whole entire your question with the entire code snippet so we can see what you are doing, besides the sole problem where we are guessing what your trying to do, it can also show if the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Ronnie Chester Lynwood: Ok, then it is not `$_GET` ;) But what is the value of `$get['url']`? If it is a string, my code should still work...

Answer (score 2):

```
$url = $get['url'];
$needle = "http://yahoo.com/";
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
if(stripos($contents, $needle) !== false) {
  $qqq = "YH";
  echo $qqq; // <--in order to echo, you need to call echo.
}
```

If your goal is just to echo `YH` if it exists, you can just call it directly with,

```
echo "YH";
```

Rather than storing it into a variable.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some confusion with your question and the title.

To answer "if $url contains http://yahoo.com/" then the following will do:

```
$url = "'".$get['url']."'";
$needle = "http://yahoo.com/";
if(stripos($url, $needle) !== false) {
  $qqq = "YH";
}
```

Of course, you can use `<?=$qqq?>` to output the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug, so break it down step by step:

```
<?PHP
// make sure you see any errors (remove this later)
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$url = $get['url'];
die($url);
?>
```

Is the URL correct?

```
<?PHP
// make sure you see any errors (remove this later)
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$url = $get['url'];
die(file_get_contents($url));
?>
```

Does your script echo what looks like the response from $url?

Then continue building out and testing...

Without seeing all of your code, nobody here will be able to guess what you're doing wrong, but it should be easy, fun, and instructional for you to figure it out for yourself.

I hope this answer sends you off in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have PHP warnings on -- you should always set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` in a development environment anyway.

Make sure you have allowed URIs as parameters for `fopen` based functions `allow_url_fopen` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen